# How to check if a record exists in octobercms?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am trying check if a record exist just the same way checking if login details (email or username) work.

```
public function onCheckEmail()
{
    return [ 'isTaken' => Auth ::findUserByLogin(post
( 'email' )) ? 1 : 0 ];
}
```

```
<label> Email address </label>
<input
name= "email"
type ="email"
class= "form-control"
data-request = "onCheckEmail"
data-request-success ="$('#loginTaken').toggle(!!data.isTaken)"
data-track-input />
</div>
<div id = "loginTaken" class= "alert alert-danger"
style = "display: none ">
Sorry, that login name is already taken.
</div>
```

I want it to work the same way as the above for a company field. But didn't work making some changes to the above

Answer (score 0):

Show us what you did to try to make it work. Things to check for: Are you receiving the post data? Is this in a component or a CMS Page? Is Ajax enabled on the page? Are you receiving an error message?

I can confirm that your copy of a code is working. I put this code in a component and the only difference is: `data-request="{{__SELF__}}::onCheckEmail"`

[image]